# does export_saved_model from TF2 save also weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I created, compiled and fitted a model with tf.keras using the latest **TF2.0a**.
Now I want to save this as a pb to be used later for inference.

I use :

```
import time
saved_model_path = "./models/pb/experimental/{}".format(int(time.time()))

tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, saved_model_path)
saved_model_path
```

as nicely described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models) under point *As a saved_model*

The `model` is the model I previously created/compiled/fitted

Now my questions,

1. how does the `export_saved_model` know which weights to save? Or does it saves the weights from the last epoch?
2. following that logic, would be best to load the best model from your checkpoint and then use the export function?
3. Add on Question: Is there a callback which functions as modelcheckpoint from keras but with this export function? creating pb files of best model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/saved_model.py

1) Keras saves the model with the last checkpoint, which are in fact the weights of the last epoch.

Cite from source:

> The `SavedModel` contains:
>
> 1. a checkpoint containing the model weights.
> 2. a `SavedModel` proto containing the Tensorflow backend graph. Separate
>      graphs are saved for prediction (serving), train, and evaluation. If
>      the model has not been compiled, then only the graph computing predictions
>      will be exported.
> 3. the model's json config. If the model is subclassed, this will only be
>      included if the model's `get_config()` method is overwritten.

2) In my opinion the best way is to always seperate between model architecture and weights when saving and loading. In other terms: Yes, load the weights from the best model.

3) No, right now there is no callback that exports the whole model to pb. So either use the "ModelCheckpoint" Callback and load the optimal weights afterwards or build your own callback with "LambdaCallback".

I hope this helps!